# Printing all the options present in a dynamic dropdown - selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium

I am working on one site where I have two drop-downs. Both are dynamic. The values in the HTML code are generated as I scroll. I want to get all the options present in the drop-down. I got the xpath for the visible items when I stored them in a list and printed them. I am getting blank values for some records in a list. [The options present in the drop-down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z60Wr.png)

Also, is there any way where I can get all the items present in the list? like the ones that are not visible. [The output I got] [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdkiP.png)

```
<div class="ant-col ant-form-item-control">
 <div class="ant-form-item-control-input">
<div class="ant-form-item-control-input-content">
<div class="ant-select ant-select-lg ant-select-single ant-select-show-arrow">
<div class="ant-select-selector">
<span class="ant-select-selection-search">
<input id="company_industry" autocomplete="off" type="search" class="ant-select-selection-search-input" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-owns="company_industry_list" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-controls="company_industry_list" aria-activedescendant="company_industry_list_9" readonly="" unselectable="on" value="" style="opacity: 0;" aria-expanded="false">
</span>
<span class="ant-select-selection-item" title="Automotive">Automotive</span></div>
<span class="ant-select-arrow" unselectable="on" aria-hidden="true" style="user-select: none;">
<span role="img" aria-label="down" class="anticon anticon-down ant-select-suffix">
<svg viewBox="64 64 896 896" focusable="false" data-icon="down" width="1em" height="1em" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
<path d="M884 256h-75c-5.1 0-9.9 2.5-12.9 6.6L512 654.2 227.9 262.6c-3-4.1-7.8-6.6-12.9-6.6h-75c-6.5 0-10.3 7.4-6.5 12.7l352.6 486.1c12.8 17.6 39 17.6 51.7 0l352.6-486.1c3.9-5.3.1-12.7-6.4-12.7z"></path></svg></span></span</div></div></div></div>
```

Java Code

```
companylist = portalElements.company_type_list();

        for (int i = 0; i < companylist.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Total company list is :" + companylist.get(i).getText());
        }
```

Companylist is my List, and the xpath for getting all the items is `//div[@class='ant-select-item ant-select-item-option']`

Comment: Add the minimal code and the `HTML` source for the elements

Comment: @Akzy I have added the sample code, Maybe this will help you find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The provided `HTML` is not enough but I am adding here one solution, this could help you.

```
driver.get("https://www.makemytrip.com/")
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@class='input_fromto checkSpecialCharacters ui-autocomplete-input' and @id='hp-widget__sfrom']"))).click();
List<WebElement> myList = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//li[@class='ui-menu-item'][starts-with(@id,'ui-id-')]//span[@class='autoCompleteItem__label']")));
for (WebElement element:myList)
  String all_options = element.getText();
    System.out.println(all_options);
```